# Can we escape the % sign used as relative unit

Tags: html, css

I have a button inside a table. I want this button to have full width relative to the table, which can be achieved by setting `width=100%` to the button.

The problem is that I am using the '%' character as a placeholder. Back-end, the server is replacing occurrences of the '%' inside the .html file by some other stuff. Up to now it worked well, because all the relative unit '%' were anyway in a different css file, but this time I have to deal with email html so I can not separate it.

So basically I am looking for a way to escape the '%' inside `width=100%`, so that at the end the result is similar but there is no '%' character.

Comment: What is the server technology used that does the replacing? Escaping% has to be supported by that technology.

Comment: Well... There's no way to know what escaping can work if it's a custom parser totally unknown for us. I supposed you mean a totally different alternative. For that, we may need to see the actual markup.

Comment: @NineBerry The placeholder '%' are replaced by a c/c++ server. The email html should then be able to be viewed by all bigger email servers like gmail.

Comment: @Álvaro González just a second, my english isnt that great. I look for something like `width=100\27` which then gmail would e.g. interpret as `width=100%`. The problem is that my parser/server which is working in between would mess up if it encounters any '%' signs inside the .html file.

Comment: Whoever wrote that c/c++ server, will have implemented a way to escape % signs. Is there no documentation?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out a simpler mechanism. (Side note: `width=100%` is a pre-CSS HTML attribute so it doesn't really have to do with CSS.)

Comment: @NineBerry Yes the c/c++ server is written by myself. And I use the '%' character as a placeholder where i replace interactive stuff like tokens, etc. inside a html file. Up to now i never used a regular '%' inside a html, like e.g. for a relative length, because all css stuff was in a separate file. But now i have to use a regular unit '%', but I would like to somehow escape it so that effect is same but there is no '%'.

Comment: If the server is yours, then just do what printf does: make `%%` the escape sequence to get a literal `%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML entities. The `%` sign is [U+0025 PERCENT SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0025/index.htm) so:

```html
<p style="width: 33&#x25;; background-color: pink;">Hello,</p>
<p style="width: 67&#x25;; background-color: pink;">World!</p>
```

Remember that HTML entities only work in HTML context:

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p>World!</p>
<style>
p:nth-child(1){
  width: 33%; /* Valid */
  background-color: pink;
}
p:nth-child(2){
  width: 33&#x25;; /* Invalid */
  background-color: pink;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @NineBerry That's an important detail. I've added it to the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Before I asked the question I tried such escaping inside the `<style></style>`, it was not working thats the reason for this question XD. Anyway its perfectly fine for me to use it inside these html context. Thank you both guys again!